# Web3J - Creation of Light Wallet takes too long

Tags: wallets, web3j, android

I am creating the wallet in my Android app, using the library Web3j:
https://web3j.io/

See the code:

```
String seed = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
ECKeyPair exKey = Keys.createEcKeyPair();

WalletFile wallet = Wallet.createLight(seed,exKey);
```

It is creating the Wallet properly, the problem is that the process takes long time, around 10 minutes.

Am I doing something wrong?

Is there another way to make it faster?

Comment: you can debug that, in your ethereum node, have you tried that ? what node are you using ?